# python how to make a vector from origin on xy graph rotate/spin

Tags: python, vector

I want to animate a vector rotating around a unit circle.

[image: animated unit circle]

matplotlib might work but I only seen tutorials how to plot one plt at a time.  I want a smooth animation of a vector rotating around like a clock hand.

the formulas for rotation I got so far:

```
2=cos1−sin1
2=sin1+cos1
```

so the angle  can be a function over time.

Answer (score 0):

i found it on youtube. It is actually using plt.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXk70QbBBo8